# Adding value from textfield

Tags: javafx, parameter-passing

I a m creating a java application and I have a problem.
Here is the code.

```
package javastackoverflow;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Javastackoverflow extends Application {
      TextField deduct2;
   Label text;
      double ammount = 0.0;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Apply");
        text = new Label(Double.toString(ammount));

       btn.setOnAction((e->{



       double getamount = Double.parseDouble(deduct2.getText());
        text.setText(Double.toString(getamount)+ ammount);
      //this is where the program is suppose to get the amount and add it to amount, notice the + sign. 
        }))

;

       deduct2 = new TextField();
        FlowPane root = new FlowPane();
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.getChildren().addAll(btn,deduct2,text);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 450);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Yo Stack");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**What it is suppose to do**

When the user enters a number into the textfield the program is suppose to
to take that number and add it to ammount = 0;

**My problem**

But when ever the using enters a new number the text changes to **That** number. Remember I would like it to add to the currant number like (currant number = 23; user enters new Number) new number = 3; I would like results to equal = 26 but right now the program shows the result 3;

**What I think**

I think the problem is in the onAction() method.
I think that the text.setText() method is displaying the currant text entered into the textfield, rather then adding it to ammount.

I alse don't think I am using the correct operator from this line of code. That may be part of the problem.

text.setText(Double.toString(getamount)+ ammount);

notice how I use the + sign, that + adds the getamount to ammount..or its supposed to. But when I change that plus sign to - or * I get this error

===============================

bad operand types for binary operator '*'

first type:  String

second type: TextField

===============================

As you can probably tell I really would like this code to be correct so if you don't understand something please comment before you report me. Then I can change it fast. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the `amount` to the `getAmount` variable when `amount = 0.0`

Try adding the new value to `getAmount`

```
package javastackoverflow;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Javastackoverflow extends Application {
      TextField deduct2;
      Label text;
      double getamount = 0.0; //Edit 1
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Apply");
        text = new Label(Double.toString(ammount));

       btn.setOnAction((e->{



       getamount += Double.parseDouble(deduct2.getText()); //Edit 2
        text.setText(Double.toString(getamount));
      //this is where the program is suppose to get the amount and add it to amount, notice the + sign. 
        }))

;

       deduct2 = new TextField();
        FlowPane root = new FlowPane();
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.getChildren().addAll(btn,deduct2,text);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 450);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Yo Stack");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Nope I got error. This question may require you to copy and paste my code and test it out.

Comment: ';' expected and then I also get the error, getmount has not been initialized